# Why this javascript effect cannot use in ie7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

why this javascript effect cannot use in ie7 ?

http://jsfiddle.net/peap/cb0nesfh/

IE7 NOT work

Why i cannot use this function in ie7

```
function over(event)
{
    $('.notch2').stop().animate({top: '33px' , opacity: 1}, 100);
    $('.mask').stop().animate({top: '0px' , opacity: 1}, 100);                          
}
```

but i can use this on ie 7

```
function over(event)
{
    $('.notch2').show();
    $('.mask').show();                         
}
```

Comment: Is your first case working in higher version of IE?

Comment: i use like but not work              `$("#love-box").css({ opacity: 1.0 }).animate({top: '0px' , opacity: 1}, 100);
            $(".notch").css({ opacity: 1.0 }).animate({top: '70px' , opacity: 1}, 100);`

Answer (score 2):

IE7 does not support CSS `opacity`. you will need to have this syntax:

```
filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);
```